# Lightweight code editor widget for Java that supports JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, swing

I'm creating a Swing application where the user should be able to edit JavaScript codes. So I need some kind of code editor embeddable in Java that supports:

- Customizable Auto-Completion (or if not already done, extensible enough to be easily implementable)
- Syntax Errors Highlight (like Netbeans or other advanced editors that can mark the lines with syntax problems)
- Color Syntax Highlighting (not very critical)

The need of it to be embeddable in Java is mainly because of the Auto-Completion which will be dynamic and very specific to the application.

Does such editor exists?

Answer (score 5):

RSyntaxTextArea supports syntax highlighting and auto completion, but not error highlighting:

http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea

Comment: Very nice. It seems to be very close to what I was looking for. I'll test it later to see if it fits the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an editor that's specifically designed to be embeddable, however there are tons of programmer's editors that are open-source and written 100% in java. Here's a list of some of them: http://java-source.net/open-source/ides